# Python regex find everything between substring and first space

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `string = "radios label="Does the command/question above meet the Rules to the left?" name="tq_utt_test" validates="required" gold="true" aggregation="agg""` and I want to be able to extract the substring within the "`name`". So in this case I want to extract "`tq_utt_test`" because it is the substring inside `name`.

I've tried regex `re.findall('name=(.*)\s', string)` which I thought would extract everything after the substring `name=` and before the first space. But after running that regex, it actually returned `"tq_utt_test" validates="required" gold="true"`. So seems like it's returning everything between `name=` and the **last space**, instead of everything between `name=` and **first space**.

Is there a way to twist this regex so that it returns **everything after** `name=` **and before the first space**?

Comment: `r"name=(.*?)\s"` but `r'name="[^"]*"'` seems much more robust. If you don't want `name=` use a capturing gorup: `r'name="([^"]*)"'`.

Comment: @ggorlen, thanks! I tried your suggestion and it works. The question you suggested also solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just do `re.findall('name=([^ ]*)\s', string)`